# Order of evaluation of logical AND (python)

Tags: python, logical-operators

In python, which is more efficient:

```
if a:
    if b:
        # do something
```

or

```
if a and b:
    # do something
```

The latter would be more efficient if `b` isn't calculated when `a` is false. But I can't seem to pinpoint whether that's the case in Python docs. Maybe someone can point me to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short-Circuiting

Python doesn't run `Y` in `X and Y` if `X` is false. You can try it out yourself:

```
if True and print("Hello1"):
    pass

if False and print("Hello2"):
    pass # "Hello2" won't be printed
```

The reason Python does this is it has something called short-circuiting which optimising logic expressions like this one. Python realises that if if `X` is false then there is no point in checking `Y` because the whole expression will be false anyway.

### How to Avoid Short-Circuiting

You can bypass this in Python by using the bitwise versions of the logic operators:

```
and -> & 
or -> |
```

For example:

```
if True & bool(print("Hello1")):
    pass

if False & bool(print("Hello2")):
    pass # "Hello2" will be printed this time
```

Note however that you need to wrap `print` in `bool` because bitwise only works on the same data types.

### Performance

I would imagine performance wise the one with only one if statement would be faster as other wise python might have to go through 2 if statements if it finds the conditions are true.

Answer (score 1):

This is called short-circuiting, and it [is mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

And the answer is, Python will not evaluate b if a is False.

Answer (score 0):

It evaluates from left to right, simple experiment

```
def iftrue1():
    print("iftrue1")
    return True

def iftrue2():
    print("iftrue2")
    return True

if iftrue1() and iftrue2():
    pass
```

This outputs

```
iftrue1
iftrue2
```